# How should I store an Azure AD Bearer Token in Next.js

Tags: next.js, azure-active-directory, jwt, next-auth, bearer-token

I'm working on a Next.js project where I've implemented authentication using NextAuth for email/password credentials. Additionally, I need to retrieve a bearer token from an Azure AD app to make authenticated calls to various endpoints from the Azure AD app.

I have a couple of questions regarding the best practices for managing Azure AD bearer tokens in this setup:

User-specific Bearer Tokens:
Should each user who is signed in have their own Azure AD bearer token? If so, what would be the recommended approach to handle this in a Next.js and if possible using NextAuth?

Server-Side vs Client-Side Storage:
Where should I store the Azure AD bearer token - server-side or client-side? Can NextAuth seamlessly handle the management of these tokens, or is there a preferred approach for securely storing and accessing them in a Next.js application?

## api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts

```
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth'
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials'
import { PrismaAdapter } from '@next-auth/prisma-adapter';
import prisma from '@/prisma/client';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'credentials',
      credentials: {
        email: { label: 'Email', type: 'email', placeholder: 'Email'},
        password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password', placeholder: 'Password'}
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        if (!credentials?.email || !credentials.password) return null;
        
        const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
          where: { email: credentials.email }
        });

        if (!user) return null;

        const passwordsMatch = await bcrypt.compare(
          credentials.password, 
          user.hashedPassword
        );

        return passwordsMatch ? user : null;
      }
    })
  ]
}

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

And the code for fetching the token would look something like the following, I am unsure as to where this would go and how this would connect up to my Next.js app.

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
myHeaders.append("Cookie", "fpc=ArnnFhTMCf1OmHBMGIeu_bbGVvFcAQAAAGZSCt0OAAAA");

var urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
urlencoded.append("grant_type", "client_credentials");
urlencoded.append("client_id", process.env.CLIENT_ID);
urlencoded.append("client_secret", process.env.CLIENT_SECRET);
urlencoded.append("scope", "https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/.default");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: urlencoded,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://login.microsoftonline.com/[TENANT_ID]/oauth2/v2.0/token", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Comment: Can you share the code you have tried?

Comment: @DasariKamali I have updated the question to contain the project code, I am unsure how it fits together.